# Memory leak after upgrade Rails 5.2 to 6.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Has anyone experienced this? We upgraded a project from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0.0 and after this, the memory consumption skyrocketed... In the release candidate environment, it works fine, but in production, the container dies because of the memory usage... The instances we have in 5.2 can do just fine with 1GB RAM, but the instances we test for Rails 6.0.0 dies immediately, even if we give them 4GB ram.

We already tested https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks, but the require gems just increased like 10 MiB in total.

We have some heavy queries but we don't know why this happens in Rails 6 and not in Rails 5.

Comment: Happened to us as well, had to rollback it. we couldn't reproduce this locally, we are trying to figure out a way to debug this.

Comment: @Yosi Ok, if you solve this problem please tell me how.

Comment: Yeah, same here. We just rolled back as it's hard to figure out where this is coming from.

Comment: This could be related: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36963

Comment: @ujh in our case we include specific libraries of rails, so this can't affect us

Answer (score 1):

This hugely depends on what gems you have.
Also, I would start by making use of a monitoring tool like Scout or NewRelic to understand where/how is the leak happening.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the issue in rails with AWS ECS Farget (Docker).

Taken actions.

1. Update latest rails 6 version (6.1.7.3)
2. Allow all ip and my domain in
   production.rb file. [check](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#actiondispatch-hostauthorization)

Now its working perfect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).